# Determining image gradient direction from sobel?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, gradient

I am attempting to determine the image gradient direction using the results from openCV's Sobel method.

I understand this should be a very simple task. I have copied the methods from a number of resources and answers from here but whatever I do the resultant directions are always between 0 - 57 degrees (I would expect the range to be from 0-360).

I believe all the depths are correct. I have tried calculating the direction using the 16S data as well as 8U data.

I just can't see where I'm going wrong? Can anyone spot my mistake?

```
void getGradients(IplImage* original, cv::Mat* gradArray)
{
    cv::Mat original_Mat(original, true);

    // Convert it to gray
    cv::cvtColor( original_Mat, original_Mat, CV_RGB2GRAY );
    //cv::blur(original_Mat, original_Mat, cv::Size(7,7));

    /// Generate grad_x and grad_y
    cv::Mat grad_x = cv::Mat::zeros(original->height, original->width, CV_16S); 
    cv::Mat grad_y = cv::Mat::zeros(original->height, original->width, CV_16S);

    cv::Mat abs_grad_x = cv::Mat::zeros(original->height, original->width, CV_8U);
    cv::Mat abs_grad_y = cv::Mat::zeros(original->height, original->width, CV_8U);;

    /// Gradient X
    cv::Sobel(original_Mat, grad_x, CV_16S, 1, 0, 3);
    cv::convertScaleAbs( grad_x, abs_grad_x );

    /// Gradient Y
    cv::Sobel(original_Mat, grad_y, CV_16S, 0, 1, 3);
    cv::convertScaleAbs( grad_y, abs_grad_y );

    uchar* pixelX = abs_grad_x.data;
    uchar* pixelY = abs_grad_y.data;
    uchar* grad1 = gradArray[0].data;
    uchar* grad2 = gradArray[1].data;
    uchar* grad3 = gradArray[2].data;
    uchar* grad4 = gradArray[3].data;
    uchar* grad5 = gradArray[4].data;
    uchar* grad6 = gradArray[5].data;
    uchar* grad7 = gradArray[6].data;
    uchar* grad8 = gradArray[7].data;
    int count = 0;
    int min = 999999;
    int max = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < grad_x.rows * grad_x.cols; i++) 
    {
            int directionRAD = atan2(pixelY[i], pixelX[i]);
            int directionDEG = directionRAD / PI * 180;

            if(directionDEG < min){min = directionDEG;}
            if(directionDEG > max){max = directionDEG;}

            if(directionDEG >= 0 && directionDEG <= 45)         { grad1[i] = 255; count++;}         
            if(directionDEG >= 45 && directionDEG <= 90)        { grad2[i] = 255; count++;}         
            if(directionDEG >= 90 && directionDEG <= 135)       { grad3[i] = 255; count++;}         
            if(directionDEG >= 135 && directionDEG <= 190)      { grad4[i] = 255; count++;}         
            if(directionDEG >= 190 && directionDEG <= 225)      { grad5[i] = 255; count++;}         
            if(directionDEG >= 225 && directionDEG <= 270)      { grad6[i] = 255; count++;}     
            if(directionDEG >= 270 && directionDEG <= 315)      { grad7[i] = 255; count++;}
            if(directionDEG >= 315 && directionDEG <= 360)      { grad8[i] = 255; count++;}

            if(directionDEG < 0 || directionDEG > 360)
            {
                cout<<"Weird gradient direction given in method: getGradients.";
            }               
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You're using integer arithmetic so your calculations for radians and degrees are suffering badly from truncation.

Also `atan2` gives a result in the range `-PI` to `+PI`, so if you want a value in degrees in the range 0..360 you'll need to add a 180 degree correction:

```
        double directionRAD = atan2(pixelY[i], pixelX[i]);
        int directionDEG = (int)(180.0 + directionRAD / M_PI * 180.0);
```

Note the use of `double` rather than `int` for `directionRAD`.

Pro tip: learn to use a debugger to step through you code, inspecting variables as you go - that will make fixing simple bugs like this a lot easier than waiting for responses on StackOverflow.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Paul. I corrected the truncation issue as you suggested however it has not made much difference. I still get a restricted number of gradient direction 0 - 90 (or 180 - 270 with the 180 degree correction applied). I no longer scale the values and thus am using the raw 16S values given by the Sobel operation.
I have stepped through the process for an entire image but can't see where it's going wrong. Do you have any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Did you remove the abs operation too ? If so, then I suggest you post your latest code as a new question.

Comment: Yes I did. I will post a new question now. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

You can get the x-derivative `dx` and y-derivative `dy` using Sobel operator. Then you can use the formula to calculate the magnitude and direction of the gradient. `G=sqrt(dx^2+dy^2), theta=arctan(dy/dx)`. You can find this is just convert descartes coordinate system(x,y) to polar coordinates(rho, theta)!

There is something wrong in your code that you make absolute value of `dx` and `dy`, which makes the direction always in the first quadrant of the Cartesian coordinate system. And the function you used `convertScaleAbs` converts the result to 8-bit, which results in the truncation error.

I have a demo to calculate the magnitude partly based on your code.

```
    const string imgname = "F:/OpenCV/square.jpg";
    Mat img = imread(imgname, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);

    // 1. convert it to gray value
    Mat gray;
    cvtColor(img, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    // 2. blur the image
    blur(gray, gray, Size(7, 7));
    // 3. sobel
    Mat grad_x, grad_y;
    Scharr(gray, grad_x, CV_32FC1, 1, 0);
    Scharr(gray, grad_y, CV_32FC1, 0, 1);
    // 4. calculate gradient magnitude and direction
    Mat magnitude, direction;
    bool useDegree = true;    // use degree or rad
    // the range of the direction is [0,2pi) or [0, 360)
    cartToPolar(grad_x, grad_y, magnitude, direction, useDegree);

    // test, the histogram of the directions
    vector<int> cnt(8, 0);   // 0-45, 45-90, ..., 315-360

    for(auto iter = direction.begin<float>(); iter != direction.end<float>(); ++iter)
    {
        int idx = static_cast<int>(*iter) / 45;
        ++cnt[idx];
    }

    Mat scaled;
    convertScaleAbs(magnitude, scaled);
    imshow("magnitude", scaled);
    for(auto v : cnt)
        cout << v << " ";
```

[image: A test picture]
      [image: magnitude visulization result]

Answer (score 2):

You take and absolute value of the gradients, which maps all angles from [-180; 180] to [0;90]. Also you use integer division.

Comment: Thanks old-ufo. I corrected the integer division issue as per Paul's advice and I only use the 16S data directly from the Sobel operation. Yet I still get a restricted range of directions from 0 - 90. Can you see anything else wrong with my code?

Comment: Please, update the code in your post, so we could find a bug in _current_ version.