# Obtain Gradient orientation in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I must find the orientation of the gradient in an image. I already obtain Gx,Gy and the total gradient.

```
//Scharr( src_gray, grad_x, ddepth, 1, 0, scale, delta, BORDER_DEFAULT );
          Sobel( img, grad_x, ddepth, 1, 0, 3, scale, delta, BORDER_DEFAULT );
          convertScaleAbs( grad_x, abs_grad_x ); //Gradiente en X

          /// Gradient Y
          //Scharr( src_gray, grad_y, ddepth, 0, 1, scale, delta, BORDER_DEFAULT );
          Sobel( img, grad_y, ddepth, 0, 1, 3, scale, delta, BORDER_DEFAULT );
          convertScaleAbs( grad_y, abs_grad_y ); //Gradiente en Y

          /// Total Gradient (approximate)
          addWeighted( abs_grad_x, 0.5, abs_grad_y, 0.5, 0, grad ); //Magnitud del Gradiente
```

Now, I must find the orientation of the gradient,but I dont find any code to get it. I know the theory but I dont know to put it in practice.

Anyone knows how can I get de orientation of the gradient?

Thanks for your time

EDIT: I tried to use this:

```
Mat modulo;
        Mat orientacion;
        cartToPolar(abs_grad_x,abs_grad_y,modulo,orientacion);
```

But it give me an error:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (X.size == Y.size && type == Y.type() && (depth == CV_32F || depth == CV_64F)) in cartToPolar, file C:\OpenCV246PC\opencv\modules\core\src\mathfuncs.cpp, line 448
```

I tried to change the depth to CV_32F and the image of gradient its not correct.

Comment: You can compute the orientation with `atan2(grad_x, grad_y)` .have a look at the answer of Paul R in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20007000/determining-image-gradient-direction-from-sobel

Comment: remark: your magnitude computation is just an approximation! If you want/need correct magnitude values use cv::magnitude. You should also work with  `grad_x/y` instead of `abs_grad_x/y` when computing orientation (same when computing orientation/magnitude with `cartToPolar`)

Comment: Note: `depth` and `type` variables refer to `X.depth()` and `X.type()`, as can be seen in OpenCV source: https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/2.4/modules/core/src/mathfuncs.cpp#L446